# Search part of text using Oracle TEXT SEARCH (CONTEXT index)

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

I am exploring Oracle Text (Context) index.
I am able to search a full word..
How to search for a part of the text?
Example, There is a text like
"There is a HTTP POSTREQUEST"
If i filter like below in my sql, I am not getting the result
*contains(text_col,'POST') > 0*
or
*contains(text_col,'OSTREQ') > 0*

--
I Understand Oracle Text is indexing the words.. Any way to search the part of the text?

Code sample for example

```
DROP TABLE test_context_tbl
;
CREATE TABLE test_context_tbl(no_col NUMBER, text_col VARCHAR2(1000))
;
INSERT INTO test_context_tbl VALUES (1,'There is a HTTP POSTREQUEST ')
;
COMMIT
;
CREATE INDEX ix_test_context ON test_context_tbl(text_col) INDEXTYPE IS ctxsys.CONTEXT
;
select * from test_context_tbl
where contains(text_col,'OSTREQ') > 0
```

Answer (score -1):

I just found the answer.. using wildcard inside contains operator works

```
select * from test_context_tbl
where contains(text_col,'%OSTREQ%') > 0
```